# Is adding ETag to strongly typed model really a bad idea?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, optimistic-concurrency

I am implementing an optimistic concurrency with DocumentDb API using .NET SDK.

On several places i have found mentioning that having `ETag` on strongly typed model is a bad idea.
Explicitly here:
https://www.google.hr/amp/s/peter.intheazuresky.com/2016/04/28/documentdb-revisited-part-3-concurrency-in-documentdb/amp/

Even official examples on github show it using `dynamic/Document` classes instead of strongly typed ones.

Now, what i dont understand is why not storing `ETag` on model?
According to docs, `ETag`, just like other resource properties (exception is `id`) is `get` only and is always changed exclusively by the server.
Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources#system-vs-user-defined-resources

So, if we put `ETag` on our model and:

1. read document from db to strongly typed model with `etag` property
2. send it to client (lets ignore for simplicity presentation layer `dto`s)
3. client updates it and send back
4. we send update/replace to cosmosdb (with `AccessCondition` set to `etag` gotten from client and still in one of the models properties)

I have a hard time finding a problem there?
Why bothering with `dynamics/Document` at all?

Or am i missing something obvious?

Comment: I have to agree with you here. I'm accessing cosmos DB via an azure http function. I also want to add the etag property to the model and DTO for returning to the client. This seems like the best way in my situation. I'm curious what you ended up doing in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Etag is server construct, and initially your document is born without it. IMHO it is a matter of how purist you want to be about your document.

As the example says you can have the ETag and have your pure object (theOrder) too

var theOrder = (Order)(dynamic)orderDoc;

Debug.WriteLine(**theOrder**.Customer.FirstName + “. Etag “ + **orderDoc**.ETag);

As per the above example you have to keep the returned document object around to get the ETag or should you have a **theOrder** object go around with Etag property which no one cares and understand till you come to concurrency.

Comment: Well, example is somewhat simplistic as it doesnt include roundtrip to client and then back to update. When you include client into mix i see no way but packing it in some kind of strongly typed object. we can now discuss if its a business model or `dto` but thats another discussion. point is that at the end of the day its having it in strongly typed object.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is bad to include the ETag on the model itself because *strong* ETags are supposed to be generated from the document bytes.

If the ETag is part of the document, that's never a possibility:

You generate the ETag from the document bytes (a hash function for example). That gives you an ETag string.
The moment you set that string on the document's ETag property, the hash doesn't match anymore, so the ETag value is wrong.

You can implement something that will ignore the ETag value in the hash function, but that will be considered a "weak" ETag.

Answer (score 0):

If Entity Framework for SQL can have `Timestamp` property added, why you can't add `etag` for cosmos?

Microsoft example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#timestamprowversion